# RegEx for a license plate

Tags: regex

I have to validate a text value with RegEx for the following possible types of expressions: (must be 8 characters with 2 hyphens and 6 alphanumeric characters.)

1. aa-99-99
2. 99-23-bd
3. 02-xx-04
4. ab-99-cz
5. sc-xd-49
6. 99-xav-4
7. 48-xyz-09
8. 9-abc-01
9. xs-899-x
10. sss-99-x

I tried the following regex pattern but it didn't work:

```
/^(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})$/
```

Comment: How is `48-xyz-09` 8 characters?

Comment: Many of these are not 8 characters.

Answer (score 4):

### Update after OP's clarification:

If you'd like to only allow letter or numbers in each block, you may use:

```
^(?=.{8}$)(?:(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)(?:-|$)){3}
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ZNaxF/1)**.

If you also want to make sure the string contains both letters and numbers, you may use the following instead:

```
^(?=.{8}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?:(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)(?:-|$)){3}
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ZNaxF/3)**.

---

### Original answer:

If I understand your requirements correctly, you may use something like this:

```
/^(?=.{8}$)[a-z0-9]{1,3}-[a-z0-9]{1,3}-[a-z0-9]{1,3}$/
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kW8RcG/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```
^             # The beginning of the string.
(?=.{8}$)     # A positive Lookahead to limit the length of the string to exactly 8 chars.
[a-z0-9]{1,3} # One to three alphanumeric (English) characters.
-             # Matches the character "-" literally.
$             # The end of the string.
```

**Update:**

If you want to avoid repeating the `[a-z0-9]{1,3}` part, you may use something like this:

```
^(?=.{8}$)(?:[a-z0-9]{1,3}(?:-|$)){3}
```

...but the pattern will not be as easy to read so I would stick with the first one.

---

### References:

- [Lookaheads and Lookbehinds in Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
- [Non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/4934172).

Comment: @ahmed abdelhameed: It worked but there is some gap i.e it should have combination of atleast one set of numbers or alphabets i.e  89-19-ab and not 99-99-99 or aa-ab-aa. How we can use ÖR?

Comment: This is a great answer and great work, but it doesn't answer OP's question. Here are the issues. 1) OP wants letters and numbers to be in blocks so `44-aa-bb` would work, but `a7-b8-c9` would not. 2) OP appears to want some combination of letters and numbers, so you cannot have a string such as `ab-cd-ef` or `12-34-56`.

Comment: Good explaination Ahmed

Comment: The combination of 10-b1-c2 is not allowed . aa-bb-01 or 10-11-ac similar can be allowed

Comment: @sai so neither of the answers satisfy this, why did you accept one?

Comment: @MatthewAnderson That wasn't clear at the beginning. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Rotem : Sorry I missed some scenarios . It seems you have tested a lot :)

Comment: It matches `11-11-11` yet.

Comment: @revo I'm still not sure if the OP wants to reject that but updated the answer anyway.

Comment: @ahmed abdehameed; Its working but (min 1 to max3)-(min 1 to max3)-(min1 to max2)  The last set should have max 2 only first two set may contain maximum 3 i.e 212-01-a,  aa-200-c are valid but not  0-20-aaa

Comment: To ensure the RegEx string contains both letters and numbers, it would be simpler to use the positive lookahead `(?=.*\d)` instead of the one that you use `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])`.

Comment: @sai Please remember to include all your rules in the question from the beginning. Anyway, you may use [`^(?=.{8}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?:(?:[a-z]{1,3}|[0-9]{1,3})-){2}(?:[a-z]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/WgkYvQ/1)

Comment: @MatthewAnderson How does `(?=.*\d)` enforce containing a letter?

Comment: It does not enforce containing a letter. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex with `m` flag on:

```
^(?=.{8}$)[^\W_]+(?:-[^\W_]+)+$
```

If you need to force a combination of both digits and letters use this:

```
^(?=.{8}$)(?![\d-]+$|[a-z-]+$)[^\W_]+(?:-[^\W_]+)+$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/9KQ1Tx/1)

Comment: It worked. Can you explain the regex how it checks the combinations

Comment: Currently it seems that you have to modify your requirements to express what you really need otherwise we can't help you very well.

Comment: No change in requirement, I'll give more clarity if you dint really understand.

Comment: 8 digit which should have two minus i.e (min 1 to max3)-(min 1 to max3)-(min1 to max2) and the combination should be at least one alphabet or number combination not all alphabets or numbers i.e 00-aa-10 is valid , 00-00-00 , aa-aa-aa is not valid

Comment: Your question doesn't include these or whatever else you may want to add later. Please edit your question.